# Bash Script: Check if multiple files are executable and output them?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

Can you make a script that iterates through a folder (for example the home directory) and prints the names of all regular files that are executable?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ c.f. [test](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) and [loops](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html).

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware that the `find` command has an `-executable` switch?

If you want to see all executable files in all subdirectories, you might do:

```
find ./ -type f -executable
```

If you want to see all executable files, but just in your directory, you might do:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable
```

Answer (score 0):

I can.

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in "$@"
do [[ -d "$d" ]] || { printf '\n"%s" not a directory\n' "$d"; continue; }
   for f in "$d"/* "$d"/.*; do [[ -f "$f" && -x "$f" ]] && ls -l "$f"; done
done
```

But use `find` as Dominique advised.
Why reinvent the wheel?

Still, there's a lot going on there that could be useful.
Let me know if you have questions.